# Python Optical Character Recognition (OCR) of a single character of unknown orientation

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract

I need to perform OCR on an image of a single character on a clear background. This is for an autonomous UAV student competition, so everything needs to be automatic and the process cannot be manually tailored in flight. The character will however be in a known set (likely capital alpha-numeric). For context, I start with an image at arbitrary orientation:

[image: Example starting image]

I then automatically determine the angle, crop down and pre-process the image before running it through OCR. The one thing that I can't automatically compute beforehand (as it's really part of the OCR process) is which of the 4 remaining orientations (see below) is correct. **This is key to my question - is it possible to set up the OCR so that it sees an A (or any character) rotated to 90, 180 or 270 degrees as an A rather than thinking it is something else such as a V?** From what I can find, OSD features seem to be available in Tesseract but I cannot get them working with single characters.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlaOr.png
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET9hr.png
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/maD0E.png
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4mth.png

Currently, I am using PyTesseract to access a Tesseract OCR installation.

```
ocrText = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgD, config='-psm 6')
```

Separately, I have been having trouble with the general accuracy of the system even when presented with a clear image at the correct orientation - any tips on that would also be useful. For instance, this is why I am using PSM 6 instead of PSM 10 - it seems to provide better accuracy, even though 10 is specifically for single characters.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: you might to check this out https://github.com/emedvedev/attention-ocr

Comment: Were you doing the SUAS competition. I am trying to develop a similar process for this years competition :D

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to perform the training with all four rotated versions of each character. You can train them as the same character (all 'A') or as distinct ones ('A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3').

Note anyway that this can degrade performance a little.

---

In your case, if the character set is known and there is a nice frame around the characters, you can very well perform the recognition by yourself, without Tesseract.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered a custom training like that (I have just been using the default English scheme included with Tesseract as we do not know the font that will be used in the competition). By 'performing the recognition yourself' are you suggesting just outputting the image and having a human recognise the characters, or writing a simple context-specific OCR engine to do it?

Comment: @jt78: "everything needs to be automatic", no ?

Comment: yes, so I would assume you meant the latter option?

Comment: Can you reccommend any tutorials or GUI tools to help ease this process? I envisioned that training would be fairly simple - you input a set of image/text pairs where each image depicts a charachter and the associated text gives the character that that image should be interpreted as. However, it seems more like the process is based on tuning existing languages and fonts?